# How to set signer name?

Tags: c#, itext7

How to set signer name in iText7?, I try to use .SetContact but it does not appear as signer name.

```
 PdfSignatureAppearance _sap = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();

 _sap
    .SetPageRect(new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(_x, _y, Models.AppSettings.Application.Core.SIGNATURE_BOX_WIDTH, Models.AppSettings.Application.Core.SIGNATURE_BOX_HEIGHT))
    .SetPageNumber(_p)
    .SetSignatureCreator(Models.AppSettings.Application.Name)
    .SetContact(_contact)
    .SetLocation(_location)
    .SetReason(_reason);

    _sap.SetSignatureGraphic(_signature_graph);
    _sap.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION);
```

[image]

I expect to have something like below:

```
Digitally signed by: 
Don2
Date: xxxxx
Reason:xxxxx
Location: xxxx
```

I try to set:

```
 _sap.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
```

but it thrown me a null exception on here:

```
 ExternalEmptySignatureContainer container = new ExternalEmptySignatureContainer();
 signer.SignExternalContainer(container, 
 Models.AppSettings.Application.Core.ESTIMATED_SIGNATURE_CONTAINER_SIZE);
```

my understanding is: **SetContact** is the signer name. CMIIW

Please help

thanks 
Don

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use `SetLayer2Text` to set a custom description or build the whole appearance (on the `GetLayer2` XObject), iText creates the description like this:

```c#
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
buf.Append("Digitally signed by ");
String name = null;
CertificateInfo.X500Name x500name = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields((X509Certificate)signCertificate);
if (x500name != null) {
    name = x500name.GetField("CN");
    if (name == null) {
        name = x500name.GetField("E");
    }
}
if (name == null) {
    name = "";
}
buf.Append(name).Append('\n');
buf.Append("Date: ").Append(SignUtils.DateToString(signDate));
if (reason != null) {
    buf.Append('\n').Append(reasonCaption).Append(reason);
}
if (location != null) {
    buf.Append('\n').Append(locationCaption).Append(location);
}
text = buf.ToString();
```

*(excerpt from the `PdfSignatureAppearance` method `GetAppearance`)*

As you see the signer *certificate* is used to determine the name of the signer. So to get a name in the description, set the signer certificate before signing

```c#
_sap.SetCertificate(SIGNER_CERTIFICATE);
```

Alternatively, as hinted at in the beginning, supply a customized description

```c#
_sap.SetLayer2Text(CUSTOM_DESCRIPTION);
```

which can show anything you want.

---

> my understanding is: SetContact is the signer name. CMIIW

According to the PDF specification:

> **ContactInfo**
> text string
> *(Optional)* Information provided by the signer to enable a recipient to contact the signer to verify the signature.
>
> EXAMPLE 3 A phone number.

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 252 – Entries in a signature dictionary)*

Thus, the contact info is not meant for the *name* of the signer but instead for some means of *contacting* him.